# Capacitor on Android Unable to "scale down" page using viewport

Tags: android, html, viewport

If you create a basic HTML page with any content on it and add this to the :

`<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=500px, initial-scale=0.1, minimum-scale=0.1, maximum-scale=10" />`

Then open this in chrome on your PC or on your android phone you will see the content scaled down as you would expect.

[image]

Now do the same in a Capacitor app and see the content it isnt scaled down.

[image]

Why is this? Why does scaling work on android in the browser but NOT in capacitor's WebView?

Note; it is possible to set `initial-scale` to a larger value `2` for example, this works both browser AND Capacitor which is really strange.

[image]

Just for completeness this is the entire HTML I am using for the above images:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <base href="/" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=500px, initial-scale=0.3, minimum-scale=0.1, maximum-scale=10" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="width: 500px; background: red">500px wide</div>
    <div style="width: 100dvw; background: purple">100dvw</div>
    <div style="width: 200px; background: green">200px wide</div>
    <div style="width: 100px; background: blue">100px wide</div>
    <div style="font-size: 10em">HELLO WORLD THIS IS SOME TEXT!</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Typical! As soon as I post this question I stumble across the answer (with some help from ChatGPT)

You have to set these two to `true` on the WebView on the Java side:

```
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

The full code (minus the package line) for my `MainActivity.java` looks like:

```java
import com.getcapacitor.BridgeActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends BridgeActivity {

 @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Grab WebView
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();

    // The Magic
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
  }
}
```

For this to work you have to give your WebView and id. Edit `activity_main.xml` so that the `WebView` tag looks like this:

```xml
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And now it works! You can scale down and up!